# How can I filter by the length of an embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For example given the BlogPost/Comments schema here:

http://mongoosejs.com/

How would I find all posts with more than five comments?  I have tried something along the lines of

```
where('comments').size.gte(5)
```

But I'm getting tripped up with the syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDb doesn't support range queries  with size operator ([Link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size)). They recommend you to create a separate field to contain the size of the list that you increment yourself.

> You cannot use $size to find a range of sizes (for example: arrays with more than 1 element). If you need to query for a range, create an extra size field that you increment when you add elements.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for some queries, it may be feasible to just list all the counts you want in or excluded using (n)or conditions.

In your example, the following query will give all documents with more than 5 comments (using standard mongodb syntax, not mongoose):

```
db.col.find({"comments":{"$exists"=>true}, "$nor":[{"comments":{"$size"=>4}}, {"comments":{"$size"=>3}}, {"comments":{"$size"=>2}}, {"comments":{"$size"=>1}}, {"comments":{"$size"=>0}}]})
```

Obviously, this is very repetitive, so it only makes sense for small boundaries, if at all. Keeping a separate count variable, as recommended in the mongodb docs, is usually the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow, but you could also use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause:

```
db.Blog.find({$where:"this.comments.length > 5"}).exec(...);
```